# Tokenize textual content using Spark SQL?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, nlp, tokenize

I an working on implementing a requirement to create a dictionary of words to documents using apache spark and mongodb.

In my scenario I have a mongo collection in which each document has some text type fields along with a field for owner of the document.

I want to parse the text content in collection docs and create a dictionary which maps words to the document and owner fields. Basically, the **key** would be a word and **value** would be **_id** and **owner** field.

The idea is to provide auto-suggestions specific to the user when he/she types in the text box in the UI based on the user's documents.
A user can create multiple documents and a word can be in multiple documents but only one user will be able to create a document.

I used mongo spark connector and I am able to load the collection docs into a data frame using spark sql.

I am not sure how to process the textual data which is in one of the dataframe columns now to extract the words.

Is there a way using Spark SQL to process the text content in the data frame column to extract/tokenize words and map it to **_id** and **owner** fields and write the results to another collection.

If not, can someone please let me know the right approach/steps on  how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Spark has support for tokenisation and other text processing tasks but it's not in the core library. Checkout the Spark MLlib:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-guide.html

And more precisely the Transformers that work on DataFrames like:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#tokenizer